# I'm trying to make a menu in c++ and I don't understand why it doesn't loop

Tags: c++

This is what I've tried so far. It might be that I'm using the worng do while syntax but I'm really stumped because I'm pretty sure I used this exact template to create a menu before. I think the condition in the while loop is wrong for some reason it ignores that line and stops the program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char selection{};
    do{
        cout << "P: Print the numbers in the vector" << endl;
        cout << "A: Add a number to the vector" << endl;
        cout << "M: Display the mean of the vector" << endl;
        cout << "S: Display the smallest number in the vector" << endl;
        cout << "L: Display the largest number in the vector" << endl;
        cout << "Q: Quit" << endl;
        cout << "Enter your selection: ";
        cin >> selection;

        if (selection == 'P' || selection == 'p'){
            cout << "You chose to print" << endl;
        }
        else if (selection == 'A' || selection == 'a'){
            cout << "You chose to add a number to the vector" << endl;
        }
        else if (selection == 'M' || selection == 'm'){
            cout << "You chose to calculate the mean" << endl;
        }
        else if (selection == 'S' || selection == 's'){
            cout << "You chose to display the smallest number" << endl;
        }
        else if (selection == 'L' || selection == 'l'){
            cout << "You chose to display the largest number" << endl;
        } 
        else if (selection == 'Q' || selection == 'q'){
            cout << "Thank you for using the program" << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Invalid selection try again" << endl;

        }
    }
    while (selection == 'Q' && selection == 'q');

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How can a `char` be equal to `Q` and `q` at the same time?

Comment: you already have the correct condition if the user entered `q` or `Q`, you do not need it twice, but you can make the loop infinite and `break` in case input was `q` or `Q`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as @Yksisarvinen wrote 
you have a problem in your condition, 
your current condition says that:
 if selection equal to Q **and** equal to q run the loop
and I'm guessing that you don't want what 
so you need to change the loop condition from this -

```
  while (selection == 'Q' && selection == 'q');
```

to this -

```
 while (selection != 'Q' && selection != 'q');
```